# Detect file drag'n'drop events in JOGL/NEWT GLWindow

Tags: java, processing, awt, jogl

The [`GLWindow`](https://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-next/javadoc/jogl/javadoc/com/jogamp/newt/opengl/GLWindow.html) provides methods to add callback listeners for mouse events, key events and window events (such as resize events), but how can we detect file drag-and-drop events, akin to the `java.awt` [`DropTarget`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/dnd/DropTarget.html)?

The motivation here is to handle drag-and-drop events in [Processing](https://processing.org/) using its JOGL-based rendering modes (`P2D` and `P3D`), which automatically create a `GLWindow` for the sketch to run in.

---

Under [NEWT Usage](https://jogamp.org/jogl/doc/NEWT-Overview.html):

> NewtCanvasAWT, representing an AWT Canvas, allows you to hook a NEWT Window into it.

I have tried the following, although I don't know whether this *should* work. Either way, it  isn't.

```
var window = new NewtCanvasAWT(glWindow);
window.setDropTarget(new DropTarget(window, DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY_OR_MOVE, new DropTargetListener() {
    @Override
    public void dragEnter(DropTargetDragEvent dtde) {
        System.out.println("test");
    }
    @Override
    public void dragOver(DropTargetDragEvent dtde) {
        System.out.println("test");
    }
    @Override
    public void dropActionChanged(DropTargetDragEvent dtde) {
        System.out.println("test");
    }
    @Override
    public void dragExit(DropTargetEvent dte) {                 
        System.out.println("test");
    }
    @Override
    public void drop(DropTargetDropEvent dtde) {
        System.out.println("test");
    }
}));
```

Comment: I'm almost sure that drag and drop isn't natively supported yet in NEWT. Rather ask your JOGL specific question on our official forum.

Comment: having a quick look I find [similar results](https://forum.jogamp.org/NEWT-Drag-and-Drop-td4037287.html): "NEWT doesn't support drag and drop as far as I know, there is a request for enhancement about that:
https://jogamp.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=1164". The post is quite old though and I hope in the past years a solution would've popped up. In the meantime, maybe [GLFW/LWGL](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3/blob/master/modules/samples/src/test/java/org/lwjgl/demo/glfw/Events.java#L285) could be an option? ...

Comment: ...if Processing is a must I'd also consider raising an issue / feature request and seeing if maybe on the Processing forums you could get suppport from ProcessingOpenGL experts like Andrés Colubri, Gottfried Haider, Jakub Valtar
, Neil C Smith, Jonathan Feinberg, etc.

Comment: I wonder: outside of the context of Processing, are there no java opengl file drag and drop examples ?

Comment: LWJGL appears to support it via GLFW. [Example](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3/blob/master/modules/samples/src/test/java/org/lwjgl/demo/glfw/Events.java#L285). I can't find a JOGL example.

Comment: I had a hard time finding a JOGL example as well. My hunch, as mentioned above, is that if JOGL is tricky, a bit of LWJGL/GLFW integration might help. It might be quite the undertaking to fully integrate into PGraphicsOpenGL/P2D/P3D though